# Counting Precision Digits

Tags: c#, decimal

How to count precision digits on a C# decimal type?

e.g. 12.001 = 3 precision digits.

I would like to thrown an error is a precision of greater than x is present.

Thanks.

Comment: So if you divide this by 2 to get 6.0005 then an exception should be thrown?  Good luck writing the math library to go along with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the "scale" of a `decimal` like this:

```
static byte GetScale(decimal d)
{
  return BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(d)[3])[2];
}
```

Explanation: [`decimal.GetBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx) returns an array of four `int` values of which we take only the last one. As described on the linked page, we need only the second to last `byte` from the four bytes that make up this `int`, and we do that with `BitConverter.GetBytes`.

Examples: The scale of the number `3.14m` is `2`. The scale of `3.14000m` is `5`. The scale of `123456m` is `0`. The scale of `123456.0m` is `1`.

---

If the code may run on a big-endian system, it is *likely* that you have to modify to `BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(d)[3])[BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? 2 : 1]` or something similar. I have not tested that. See the comments by relatively_random below.

Comment: Would this still work on a system with different endianness?

Comment: @relatively_random Not sure. Are there implementations of .NET running on big-endian systems? I think we would have to consult the documentations of `decimal.GetBits` and `BitConverter.GetBytes` from those implementation of .NET to find out if their outputs depend on the endianness. I see Microsoft .NET has a field `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`, I do not know if they built their framework for big-endian architecture. Related: [Details about Endian-ness and .Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162986/)

Comment: According to your link, there are big-endian .NET implementations. BitConverter is sensitive to endianness, according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx). And I would interpret what is written about [Decimal.GetBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx) that it produces the same output regardless of the machine. So the method should probably be modified to check for BitConverter.IsLittleEndian and to get byte index 1 if false.

Answer (score 3):

```
public int CountDecPoint(decimal d){
   string[] s = d.ToString().Split('.');
   return s.Length == 1 ? 0 : s[1].Length;
}
```

Normally the decimal separator is `.`, but to deal with different culture, this code will be better:

```
public int CountDecPoint(decimal d){
   string[] s = d.ToString().Split(Application.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0]);
   return s.Length == 1 ? 0 : s[1].Length;
}
```

Comment: Downside though, this isn't going to perform well if you're making lots of calls.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm resurrecting an ancient question, but here's a version that doesn't rely on string representations and actually ignores trailing zeros. If that's even desired, of course.

```
public static int GetMinPrecision(this decimal input)
{
    if (input < 0)
        input = -input;

    int count = 0;
    input -= decimal.Truncate(input);
    while (input != 0)
    {
        ++count;
        input *= 10;
        input -= decimal.Truncate(input);
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to thrown an error is a precision of greater than x is present*

This looks like the simplest way:

```
void AssertPrecision(decimal number, int decimals)
{
    if (number != decimal.Round(number, decimals, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))
        throw new Exception()
};
```